# If $P = (1+ \cos x)(1+ \cos y)(1+ \cos z) = (1- \cos x)(1- \cos y)(1- \cos z)$, then $P = |\sin x\sin y \sin z|$

Tags: trigonometry

If we know ...
$$P = (1+ \cos x)(1+ \cos y)(1+ \cos z) = (1- \cos x)(1- \cos y)(1- \cos z)$$
... then prove ...
$$P = |\sin x\sin y \sin z|$$

Comment: What is $\P$? what did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Compute $P^2$ by multiplying the two different expressions. Use difference of squares and a basic trig identity.

Answer (score 2):

Notice,

$$P^2 = P \cdot P = (1+\cos x)(1+\cos y)(1+\cos z) \cdot (1-\cos x)(1-\cos y)(1-\cos z)$$
$$=(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)\cdot (1+\cos y)(1-\cos y)\cdot(1+\cos z)(1-\cos z)$$
$$=(1-\cos^2x)(1-\cos^2y)(1-\cos^2z)$$

Then, applying the identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$ yields,

$$P^2 = \sin^2x \cdot \sin^2y \cdot \sin^2z = (\sin x \cdot \sin y \cdot \sin z)^2.$$

Applying the square root to both sides,
$$|P| = |\sin x \cdot \sin y \cdot \sin z|.$$

Since $1+\cos x \geq0$ for all $x$, one can show that $P$ is non-negative and thus $|P| = P$ so we finally have,
$$P = |\sin x \cdot \sin y \cdot \sin z|.$$